# How to construct ideal low pass filter in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Firstly, I was asked to construct a signal $x(t)= 2 \cos(2 \pi f_1 t) + 1.5 \sin(2 \pi f_2 t) $ with $f_1= 100, f_2=200, t= 50 \textrm{ms}, Fs= 1\textrm{kHz}$ and number of FFT points $N = 1024$ and my code until this part is below.

```
f1=100;
f2=200;
fs= 1000;
N= 1024;
t=0:1/fs: 0.05;

x= 2*cos(2*pi*f1*t) + 1.5*sin(2*pi*f2*t)
```

I don't know that if this is the ideal low pass filter with frequency $f_c$, how to construct it in MATLAB?

[image]

Comment: 1) It is not the ideal low pass filter, 2) $Fs$ does not come into play, neither on formulas or code (so, why define it?). A discrete signal would be indexed by some variable $n$ denoting the $n^{th}$ sample, 3) The sketch does not correspond to the spectrum of $x$. $x$ is only composed of two spectral lines at $f_1$, $f_2$. Do you think you could do a little bit of reading on the [ideal low pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_filter) and come back if you still have difficulties? In the meantime, please keep in mind, questions requesting code to spec are off topic in DSP.SE

Answer (score 1):

The ideal lowpass filter is an infinitely long [sinc function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html). It's Fourier transform is a rectangular shape as shown in your frequency spectrum diagram. In practice you have to window (truncate) it to a certain number of samples. The periodic width of the lobes of the sinc will correspond to the width of your frequency rectangle (lowpass cutoff frequency)